# Can low voltage damage laptop or it's battery?

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery, voltage, charger

Sometimes I get very low voltage in my house. I am worried if I connect my laptop charger to the socket, will it damage the charger, battery or the laptop itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends. Power supplies operate on different ranges. You can check on the side of your charging cable for the specifications (usually somewhere around 100-240 Volts). If the low voltage is outside this range, it can damage the power supply and possibly the battery or laptop.

This problem can be mitigated with an Uninterruptible Power Supply, or by keeping your laptop and charger unplugged during periods of variable voltage.

Answer (score 1):

I have same experience and it damaged my laptop battery and charger of it. You need UPS or need to unplug for such fluctuating voltage.